# No result from hyperpay after integration

Tags: flutter, dart, payment, payment-processing

I'm trying to integrate with HyperPay for payment .
I'm using there demo for test .
This is the demo [demoUrl](https://github.com/HyperpayOpenSource/flutter-demo)
And I got this response

> payment_statusData: {result: {code: 200.300.404, description: invalid
> or missing parameter, parameterErrors: [{name: shopperResultUrl,
> value: com.share.flutter_app://result, message: invalid uri}, {name:
> notificationUrl, value: com.share.flutter_app://result, message:
> Notification url must be present if shopperResultUrl is not a valid
> url}]}, buildNumber:
> d32f3f32d2e4068242e61427fea24aeac7a91bbc@2021-12-20 12:03:32 +0000,
> timestamp: 2021-12-22 04:27:27+0000, ndc:
> C1929442E209D3D4A89F405ADAB52D07.uat01-vm-tx03}

I can't understand what is the matter .
so can anyone help me in my problem , please !

Comment: https://peachpayments.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004249912-Common-errors-with-the-Copy-and-Pay-integration

Comment: @AnmolMishra I read it but can't detect the missing parameter

Comment: TextEditingController() replace to TextEditingController().text

Comment: i'm facing version error in your code

Comment: the error was the _ in package  com.share.flutter_app

Comment: can you share error ss

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix

In step 1 you have probably used the live endpoint with test credentials (LIVE Authorization and Test entityId) or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

you should change the paymentMode  feom test  to live